# Checking if the mouse is clicked in Java

Tags: java, swing, click, mouse, mouselistener

I am writing a GUI in Java. I need to know how to check if the user clicks the mouse. I know how to check the position of the mouse, but I just need to check if it's clicked.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This class demonstrates how to load an Image from an external file
 */
public class LoadImageApp extends Component {

    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 70, null);
    }

    public LoadImageApp() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new LoadImageApp());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(true);
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point b = a.getLocation();
            int x = (int) b.getX();
            int y = (int) b.getY();

            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);
        }
        }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouseClicked");  
        }
}
```

this is all my code, so please just explain how to impliment that one mouse checker thing.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Swing application?

Comment: Umm... I don't think so it just:

Comment: Creates a new window. then it loads an image (or images) and displays them on that new window. I am manually making buttons (the images are the buttons and I have the animation covered) but I need to take the x and y coords (I have the x and y) and check if it's clicked (I don't know how to do that part.)

Answer (score 5):

Implement the `MouseListener` interface and put your code inside the `mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)` method. Then add an instance of this class as a listener to your component.

Basically, you create a class like this:

```
class myMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { 
       //Put the code you want here
       //...
       //...
     }

     @Override
     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) { }

     @Override
     public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) { }

     @Override
     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) { }

     @Override
     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) { }

}
```

Then you simple create a new instance of this new class with myMouseListener

```
myMouseListener mml = new myMouseListener();
```

And you add it as a listener to your component. Something like:

```
myPanel.addMouseListener(mml);
```

All information here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html

Comment: I just started (literally today), can you dumb it down please and clarify?

Comment: @user2548787 Frankly, it doesn't get much dumber then that.  Check [How to write a mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

Comment: @MadProgrammer none taken.

Comment: Um, thanks, but what about "myPanel"? Do I have to make that myself or do I just use the "img" variable (stores one of my images)? Thanks!

Comment: @user2548787 Without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), we have no idea of the structure of your program or variables.  Check out the linked tutorial from my previous comment to see if you can figure out how to fit it within your application

Comment: No offense @user2548787 but it seems like you're a little in over your head with the Java language and what you're trying to do right now. I'd start somewhere simpler (no GUI) to learn.

Comment: @Kon I already did for the first 7 hours of the day just practiced making command lines for custom applications. I need to know just how to impliment this. I understand everything but is there a predefined thing that just tells me if the mouse is clicked or not? Here is my code:

Comment: Well what GUI components are you working with? JFrames? JPanels? What? And if you truly know how to tell if a mouse is inside of a component then you should see how similar this method is.

Comment: I am not using any GUI components I don't think but check my code and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Or here, how about someone uses the above answer code and makes it into a full sample program that I can copy and paste so I can see how it works and then write my program after I understand it.

Comment: @user2548787 This is not really a code writing service, this is a question answering service. Unfortunately you're not asking a question, you're asking somebody to build you something.